# get the filename from file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Hello how do I return the filename with extension using file_get_contents
here is my code :

```
$lien ="http://www.miawmiaw.com/coolimage.jpg";

  $data = file_get_contents($lien);
  $fichier = basename($lien); 
  $fp = fopen("products/".$fichier,"wb");
  if (!$fp) exit;
  fwrite($fp, $data);
  fclose($fp);
```

so here $fichier should have the file name such as "coolimage.jpg"

Comment: Why do you want it? You already know the filename don't you? Also, `$path` is not defined in your code.

Answer (score 5):

you have used `$path` inside `basename($path);` instead of this just pass `$lien` inside the method

```
  $lien ="http://www.miawmiaw.com/coolimage.jpg";

  $data = file_get_contents($lien);
  $fichier = basename($lien); 
  $fp = fopen("products/".$fichier,"wb");
  if (!$fp) exit;
  fwrite($fp, $data);
  fclose($fp);
```

Comment: yea yea sorry mistake

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/basename)

```
$filename = basename("http://www.miawmiaw.com/coolimage.jpg");
```

Example: http://codepad.org/4ajeBuig